# High RAM Usage By App android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, large-files

My App Using Ram Too Much
it download image from webservice and show to user at 
user can change current image by click on tumb images at footer

maybe some images show to user In one activity, i finished any activity after backpress
Images size: 960 * 1186
i user system.gc() and Bitmapfactory.options variable to manage RAM Usage
but not work correctly

[image: Ram Usage Image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library) for image downloading since it is tested by wider range of users (e.g. lower probability to have memory leaks)

The other option is to use memory debugging tools explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088159/how-to-minimize-gc-for-alloc-occurences/14088280#14088280)